# Flexslider sliding doesn't resume after using next/previous controls

Tags: jquery, css, slider, dreamweaver, flexslider

No jquery background, just wanted a simple carousel for dreamweaver built site. All working nicely BUT - when you click on the next/previous arrows to move a slide forward/backward, on moving your cursor off the slider (arrows disappear) the image stays stuck on the last image you viewed instead of continuing/resuming functioning as a slider.  Is this meant to happen?  If so, is there any way to make it resume 'play'?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in your js code:

**Solution 1:**

```
$('.flex-next').on('click',function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
});
$('.flex-prev').on('click',function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/n9JUc/22/

**Solution 2:** Add this in your `flexslider` initialisation code.

```
after: function (slider) {            
        if (!slider.playing) {
            slider.play();
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/n9JUc/23/

Basically, whenever the next/prev buttons are clicked, we call the `play` method, where `.flex-next` and `.flex-prev` are the classes on next and previous buttons.

In your website, you have used:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
$('.flex-next').on('click', function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
});
$('.flex-prev').on('click', function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
});
```

Instead, just use this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        after: function (slider) {
            if (!slider.playing) {
                slider.play();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Use $(document).ready instead of $(window).load

Comment: thanks - can't get either options to work!  I have jquery.min.js and jquery.flexslider.js and also tried it in the <head> tag too, it's still doing the same thing.  Get syntax error. There are more characters when you go to the 'demo' link than are in the boxes above.  Sorry.  My slider is at [link](http://www.charlieapple.co.uk)

Comment: Updated the answer. Check for the modified code in the end of answer

Comment: How it can be again enable on hover pause slider?

Comment: Sry, when i use .flexslider("play") option "Pause on hover" stop work.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `pauseOnAction` parameter to `false`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        pauseOnAction: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   slideshowSpeed: 1000,
   start: function(slider) {
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
   },
   after: function (slider) {
      if (!slider.playing) {
        slider.play();
      }
   }
});
```